# Unable to connect to a server using fsockopen

Tags: php, ftp, nginx, fsockopen, ftps

Error in nginx error log : 
`fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in <file> on line <no>`

I am able to connect using FileZilla, WinSCP and also ftp_ssl_connect(). But I am not able to connect using `fsockopen("ssl://domain.com", $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout)`.

This command `openssl s_client -connect domain.com:21 -starttls ftp` gives me proper output, but if I remove the STARTTLS command it gives this error :

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
47404513277584:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:766:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 321 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Can anyone help me how to put STARTTLS command in my PHP code ? Please let me know if you guys need any other details I will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 465 port. For better answer please provide some info (some php code or if you are using a dedicated php class like PhpMailer please specify it)